# load different styles when click in an option of radio button

Tags: css, richfaces, richdatatable

I found this great information about my problem to fix headers of richdatatable and their columns (http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html).
I have 3 items of `<h:selectOneRadio>` when I choose one option of RadioButton the datatable load 15 column, the second 13 and the third 15. The problem is when I choose the second radioButton I have different columns and the header don't align i try to align the first datatable from tablasVH.css, the second option from tablasSoatProvincia.css.

```
<h:panelGroup id="idPanelStyle">
<h:outputStylesheet name="#{listarServicioEnMonitoreoAsesoriaController.clasificacionUbigeo eq 'CLAS01' ? 'css/tablasVH.css' : 'css/estilosTablas.css'}"/>
<h:outputStylesheet name="#{listarServicioEnMonitoreoAsesoriaController.clasificacionUbigeo eq 'CLAS04' ? 'css/tablasSoatProvincia.css' : 'css/estilosTablas.css'}"/>
<h:outputStylesheet name="#{listarServicioEnMonitoreoAsesoriaController.clasificacionUbigeo eq 'CLAS05' ? 'css/tablasSoatLima.css' : 'css/estilosTablas.css'}"/>

<div class="outer" style="position:fixed;  margin-top:31px; height:100%;">          
<div class="innera" style="margin-top:20px; height:100%;">
<rich:dataTable id="solicitudMonitoreoVehicular"
value="#{listarServicioEnMonitoreoAsesoriaController.lstSolicitudMonitoreoVehicular}"
var="item" columnClasses="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,
col12,col13,col14,col15" headerClass="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,
col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15" >...
```

Comment: What about render columns based on radioButton value?

Comment: radio button render the datatable style

Comment: It is not the same. My proposal was render column: if option A is selected then column x is displayed in table, if option B is selected then column x is not displayed.

Comment: `<rich:extendedDataTable>` comes with fixed headers, can't you use that?

Comment: I use rich:Datatable, I found the solution to my problem works for internet explorer and firefox